# How to hide and show multiple div(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div(s) in my code but when I click on any of the div all the hidden division are shown but I want that on click of a particular div only the hidden division of that slide down and on clicking outside it hides

The link for the code is http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/89/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $(".showup").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $(".showup").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup").hide();
});
```

```css
body{margin:50px;}

.showup{width:100px;height:100px; background:red; display:none;}
.click{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="click">click me</div>
<div class="showup">something I want to show</div>
<div class="click">click me</div>
<div class="showup">something I want to show</div>
<div class="click">click me</div>
<div class="showup">something I want to show</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target only the next element of clicked element. for which you can use `.next()` along with clicked elements context `this`. Like this:

```
$('.click').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b29cn8qa/)**

**Update:**

> *Actually I want that when I click on the first click here and then click on the second one then the div of the First one should hide and the second one to open*

```
$('.click').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".showup").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast");
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**[Demo for updated answer](http://jsfiddle.net/4ptznbrm/)**

Comment: Actually I want that when I click on the first click here and then click on the second one then the div of the First one should hide and the second one to open

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/90/

```
 $('.click').click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
             $(this).next(".showup").slideToggle("fast");
        });
```

Comment: Actually I want that when I click on the first click here and then click on the second one then the div of the First one should hide and the second one to open

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).next()` to reference the next element that you want to show/hide.

Checkout my answer in the code-snippet.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click', function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.click {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.showup {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">Click Me</div>
<div class="showup">You clicked the first div</div>
<br>
<div class="click">Click Me</div>
<div class="showup">You clicked the Second div</div>
<br>
<div class="click">Click Me</div>
<div class="showup">You clicked the Third div</div>
```